# Yocto Toaster stuck in Tasks starting

Tags: linux, kernel, yocto

I am using the Yocto toaster to build a x86 intel image
https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/toaster-manual/toaster-manual.html#toaster-manual-intro
However, when I click "Build selected recipes" and go to Builds, it shows:

```
ovmf-shell-image-enrollkeys
Tasks starting...
```

There is a question mark before Tasks starting and when I click on it, it displays the following message:

```
This build is waiting for tasks to start...
```

I don't know how to solve it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Check your build/toaster_ui.log, you may see python code for handling the toaster bitbake command crash or what happend with your build

With my case, it's describe in this topic
https://github.com/crops/toaster-container/issues/32